# Best way to reduce repeated code in C# - Need to create function for DateTime convert

Tags: c#

I've written the below code in C# and want to prevent re-writing the try statement each time.

1. Is this the best way to reduce repeated code when using multiple objects, create a code once function and is the function written correctly?
2. I cannot use the "GoTo" in the scope, can someone please why and how to get around this?

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter DOB for member {0} - yyyy - mm - dd format", memberName);
//enter DOB for object, also create DateTime struct instance below,"d" is just a reference
DateTime d = new DateTime();
string dob = Console.ReadLine();
//pass string to convert to Date tinme
try 
{ 
    d = Convert.ToDateTime(dob); 
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Exception in date. This record cannot be stored");
    goto again1; 
}

Console.WriteLine("Enter Date of Order {0} - yyyy - mm - dd format", memberName);
//enter DOB for object, also create DateTime struct instance below,"dor" is just a reference
DateTime dor = new DateTime();
string dorder = Console.ReadLine();
//pass string to convert to Date tinme
try 
{ 
    dor = Convert.ToDateTime(dorder); 
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Exception in date. This record cannot be stored");
    goto again1;
}

//my attempted reduce code local function
DateTime StringToDateConvert (DateTime structref, string dateoforder) 
{
    try 
    { 
        structref = Convert.ToDateTime(dateoforder); 
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Exception in date. This record cannot be stored");
        goto again1;
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Do not use `goto`. Forget that it even is supported.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because your question with its _["no actual problem to be solved"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)_, kinda sounds like _code improvement_ and/or _review_ and if so may be off-topic for SO.  It _may_ be better suited for another SE site but be sure to read the relevant FAQ; and/or re-wording your question as necessary before cross-posting.  [ask].  Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

No, this is not the best way to convert a string to `DateTime` since there is already a [`DateTime.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=net-5.0) which avoids using exceptions to handle common cases:

```
bool isValidBirthDate = DateTime.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out DateTime dob);
```

So in this case, since you want to repeat asking the user for the birth-date, use a loop:

```
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Date of Order {0} - yyyy - mm - dd format", memberName);
} while (!DateTime.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out DateTime dob));

// now you have a valid DateTime in dob
```

If you want to provide a specific format that doesn't work automatically, have a look at [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=net-5.0) and learn [how format-specifier work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

Regarding the `goto`s: just don't use them. Use loops, methods, etc, you simply don't need them.